# Issue with passing a constant pointer as an argument to another function

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, arguments

So I'm having an issue with some code that I'm writing. A simplistic version of this code is something like this:

```
typedef unsigned int Variable_one;

int original_function(Variable_one *const v1){
   if (validation(v1)) {
      /*body*/
   }
   /* more body */
}

int validation(Variable_one v1) {
   if (v1 == NULL) {
      /* even more body */
   }
}
```

I know that Variable_one is an unsigned int, but a check I have to perform is if the v1 is passed into the validation function is a Null value. Whenever I try this, even if I do

```
if (validation(*v1))
```

I still get the same error (due to compiler settings), which is 'comparison between pointer and integer.' As far as modifying the function signatures or Variable_one, I can't, because of restrictions of the project.

Comment: You're passing a pointer where a non pointer is required. `Variable_one` is a horrible name for a type...

Comment: I can modify the bodies of each, including the function call. However, the function signatures are untouchable. And if I don't need to pass the pointer, how do I validate that v1 is an appropriate value by calling the validation function?

Comment: And as far as the names, I'm using it for the sake of the example. My code is much more appropriately named.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the right datatype to the right parameter and then ask for the value at that pointer with a *

Here you go;

```
int validation(Variable_one *const v1) 
{ 
if (*v1 == NULL) { /* even more body */ }
}
```